# "And you shall place My words upon your heart" - even in exile

Tags: sources-mekorot, rashi, messiah, eretz-yisrael, ekev

In parasahas Eikev [(Devarim 11:18)](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.11.18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), the Torah instructs us that we:

> shall lay up these my words in your heart and in your soul, and bind them for a sign upon your hand, and they will be as frontlets between your eyes.

There is a [famous Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.11.18?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) on this posuk, where he explains that this means:

> Even after you have been banished make yourselves distinctive by means
> of My commands: lay Tephillin, attach Mezuzoth to your doorposts, so
> that these shall not be novelties to you when you return.

Shouldn't the reason why we need to follow Torah and the mitzvos be in order to a) follow Hashem's will, b) make ourselves a better person? G-d asks that we follow His Torah. Shouldn't that be enough reason to observe the mitzvos?

Why does Rashi says that we need to "lay up these words in our hearts", in order that, when we arrive in Eretz Yisroel when Moshiach comes, we know what to do, we know how to put on tefillin etc...

The question is whether Rashi's reasons for observing these mitzvos invalidate doing them for the obvious reasons mentioned above.

On a side note, the Piaseczno Rebbe in [Aish Kodesh](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/637563/p/51/t/0.82505802009428941234/fs/7oVeDCX8w2HLXM0t49drPmkv6jbRc2zJC9Rzw1O4er6i/start/78/end/130/c) writes that the reason why the Torah was not given in Eretz Yisrael was to give the message that the Torah can be observed everywhere, not only in Eretz Yisroel, hence it was given in the dessert.

> לכן אילו קבלו ישראל את התורה בארצם בארץ ישראל היו חושבים שרק במקומם ובביתם אפשר להם לקיים אותה ולא כשהם בגולה ומטורדים לכן נתן ד' להם התורה במדבר בדרך וטלטול שידעו שבכל מקום צריכים לקיימה כנאמר לעיל שלא יהא לבך חלוק על המקום

This all made me wondering if this Rashi does not contradict the fact that we keep mitzvos is because Hashem said that we need to observe them.

Comment: @יהושעק yes, thats what I meant

Comment: @יהושעק I edited the question. Clearer now?

Comment: Much. Thank you, Shmuel!

Comment: To the ones who voted to close. Please let me know what is unclear, and I will do my best to resolve this.

Answer (score 3):

The [gur aryeh](https://www.sefaria.org/Gur_Aryeh_on_Devarim.11.18.1) asks and answers your questions:

> אף לאחר שתגלו. דאם לא כן, מאי ענין "ושמתם" אל "ואבדתם מהרה" (פסוק יז), אלא 'אף אחר שתגלו וכו''. והא דכתיב (פסוק כא) "למען ירבו ימיכם על האדמה", יש לומר כמו שפירש הרמב"ן, שתהיו שבים אל הארץ, ותאריכו ימים שם. ולי נראה דהאי קרא "ושמתם את דברי" בכל זמן איירי, לעולם אתם חייבים במצות האלו, אלא שלכך סמך אל "ואבדתם" לומר שאף אחר שתגלו תהיו חייבים במצות, וכן פירש הרא"ם:
> אבל מה שכתב (רש"י) 'כדי שלא יהא דומים אליכם כחדשים', קשה, דהרי בלא טעם זה חייבים, דהא כל מצוה שהיא חובת הגוף חייבים בין בארץ בין בחוצה לארץ (קידושין לו ע"ב). ויש מפרשים, כי כאשר גלו בין האומות, ואין לישראל מקומות ובתים בפני עצמם, רק על דרך שאלה ושכירות, ואם כן לא יקיימו ישראל מצות מזוזה בגלות, שאין להם בתים מיוחדים. וכן תפילין, מפני שצריך שלא יסיח דעתו מן התפילין (מנחות לו ע"ב), דבימיהם דאגת וטרדת הגלות יותר, וגורם היה היסח הדעת. ובגלות גדול כמו שהיה להם, ראוי שיהיה פטורים מתפילין, כי איך לא יהיה להם היסח הדעת. ואם כן יהיו המצות עליהם חדשים כשיחזרו (לברך) [לארץ]. לכך אמר שאף בחוצה לארץ יקנו להם בתים, כדי שיעשו מזוזה. וגם בגלות יסירו הטרדות ויתחייבו בתפילין, כדי שלא יהיו נראים חדשים מזוזה ותפילין עליהם:
> But what (Rashi) wrote, 'so that they will not be to you as new', is difficult, since without this reason it is obligatory, for isn't it that every mitzvah which is the duty of the body obligatory both in the land and outside of the land i.e. israel (Kiddoshin 36b). There are those who answer, because when they were exiled among the nations, and Israel does not have places and houses of their own, only by way of borrowing and renting, and if so Israel will not observe the mitzvah of mezuzah in exile, since they do not have their own houses. As well as tefillin, because it is necessary that one's mind not be distracted from the tefillin (menachot 36b), because in that time the exile was more burdensome, and was the cause of distraction. And in an exile as great as they had, it is appropriate that they be exempted from tefillin, because how would they not be distracted. And if so, the mizvot will be new to them when they return to Israel. Therefore he said that even when in exile they will buy houses for them, so that they can make mezuzah. And in exile they will remove harassment and commit themselves to tefillin, so that they will not be seen as new with mezuzah and tefillin on them:
> והרמב"ן נתעורר בזה ואמר שיש לזה סוד עמוק81. ואני אגלה הסוד. כתב הרמב"ן בפרשת תולדות (בראשית כו, ה) כי התורה היא "משפט אלקי הארץ" (מ"ב יז, כו), ולפיכך היו האבות שומרים את התורה דוקא בארץ, לא בחוצה לארץ, לפי שלא נצטוו בה. אבל ישראל, כל מצוה שהיא חובת הגוף חייב לעשות, ולא היה ראוי שישראל ישמרו המצות בחוצה לארץ, כיון שהם "משפט אלקי הארץ", אבל אם לא נתן השם יתברך שישמרו המצות בחוצה לארץ ושיקיימו אותם כמו בארץ, היה בבואם לארץ אחר כך נתינה חדשה, כיון שכבר נתבטלו המצות חס ושלום. ואין כאן נתינה חדשה, ולכך אמר שלכך יקיימו המצות בחוצה לארץ גם כן, שאם לא כן היה צריך שיהיו המצות בבואם לארץ חדשים, ואין כאן דבר חדש כלל, שפעם אחת נתנה התורה מן השם יתברך, ולא שתי פעמים. ולפיכך כל מצות שהם חובת הגוף חייבין בחוצה לארץ. ומה שאמר 'כדי שלא יהיו חדשים עליכם', הוא בעצמו טעם הכתוב שחייב כל מצות שהם חובת הגוף, וחייבים עליהם בחוצה לארץ כמו בארץ, שהרי אין כאן מצות חדשות, וחיוב הראשון לא נתבטל, כדי שלא יהיו חדשים כשיחזרו לארץ. ונכון הוא מאד:

(I'm working on the English translation)

Comment: This seems to be very on the pshat-level. Thanks, though. Ofcourse we have houses, so we can do the mitzvah of mezuzah. But why "make yourselves distinctive"?

Answer (score 2):

[Ramban to Vayikra 18:25](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ramban_on_Leviticus.18.25?lang=bi) addresses the *midrash* upon which this Rashi is based. The key line is:

> ופירשו בהן כדי שלא יהו חדשים עלינו כשנחזור לארץ **כי עיקר כל המצות ליושבים בארץ ה**'‏
>
> [T]he Rabbis [in the above text of the Sifre] explained [that we must observe them] so that they shall not be novelties to us when we return to the Land, **for the main [fulfillment] of the commandments is [to be kept] when dwelling in the Land of G-d**.

So according to Ramban, the *midrash* is explaining to us why Hashem commanded us to follow *mitzvot* in *chutz laaretz*. The reason for doing so is to make sure that eventually we will be able to observe them in *eretz yisrael*, because that is where and how they are meant to be fulfilled.